# jQuery mobile: Popup and vclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile for a project and need to react to vclick events when a popup is opened.
My problem is that the vclick event is just fired inside the popup, not on the whole page.
You can find a minimal example here.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly, I dont know if this was your intention but you are using [popup overlay panel](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-panels.html). Unlike normal panel in jQuery Mobile 1.3 version, popup overlay panel has an hidden div witch stretches full width and full height of the screen.

What looks like a click on a mail page is just a click on a hidden overlay div.

You can even test this, use Firefox or Chrome and take a look at a popup HTML, you will find that DIV.

In your case this DIv is a problem:

```
<div id="panelPopup-screen" class="ui-popup-screen in" style="height: 611px;"></div>
```

You can always switch to jQuery Mobile 1.3 RC1, use its panel, just make it semi transparent.

**EDIT :**

Found a solution for you, here's a live working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SC8hH/

This will fix your problem:

```
#panelPopup-screen {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to switch to the new panels, but I did not manage to adjust their height (I don't want them to use the complete window height) and they somehow break my background color (switches to white if I use the new panels). Do you have any experiences with that?